# How to configure non-root user on Synology NAS?

Tags: linux, ssh, nas

I figured out how to login, just use `ssh <username>@<ip>` with appropriate password. However, when I login, it says:

> Synology strongly advises you not to run commands as the root user, who has
> the highest privileges on the system. Doing so may cause major damages
> to the system. Please note that if you choose to proceed, all consequences are
> at your own risk.

How do i create a non-root user and configure that so I can login as the non-root user?

I just tried to create a second user with read/write permissions, but it gives me the same warning message.